# Symfony 6.1 Doctrine QueryBuilder "class xxx is not defined"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I'm trying to move a Symfony 3.4 app to 6.1. I've done this by creating a brand new, clean 6.1 app and am copying things over.

I'm stuck with some Doctrine queryBuilders, eg.

```
$this->query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('c')
                    ->from('Customer' , 'c');
```

This code is in a Controller, not a Repository. This gives the error

`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'Customer c ORDER': Error: Class 'Customer' is not defined.`

In the 3.4 version, 'Customer' was prefixed by the bundle name. In the 6.1 version, there is no bundle. I understand that the bundle name in 3.4 showed Doctrine which Entity 'Customer' referred to, how do I do the same in 6.1 with no bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing with App\Entity\ works! Eg:

```
$this->query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('c')
                    ->from('App\Entity\Customer' , 'c');
```

Comment: Or you could save a couple of keystrokes with `from(Customer::class, 'c')`